# Is is possible to run cmd commands straight from VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, command-line, cmd

Is is possible to run cmd commands straight from VB. I want to be able to set up a command in vb without showing the black cmd window

```
path= C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft.jar nogui
```

Is it possible to run it without making a batch file? ( I want be be able to change some of the values in the commands to)

I found `Shell(pathname[,windowstyle])` but I am not quite sure how to use it or if it is the right code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

```
Dim pi As new ProcessStartInfo("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java")
pi.Arguments = "-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft.jar nogui"

Process.Start(pi)
```

I have use [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfbyhds5.aspx) to hold the process information before starting it off.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Process.Start static Method
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)